# How can I obtain site's root url and route for "rqrcode-rails3"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to generate QR codes of each shop's url.

For example, I have Shop model and all of them have name for each.
I can generate QR code by this

> @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( url, :size => 4, :level => :h )

How can I define 'url' here?

How can I obtain the combination of Site's URL and controller_action_url thing??
It should be something like this

url = root.site_path + '/' + shop_url(params[:id])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shop_url already gives the full url